# Concatenation in java?

Tags: java

In PHP you can concatenate strings with .= so that the string grows with what ever you add to it. I wonder if this could be done in java? I made some test in this code, to add all number into one long string, but not working! Could it be done in some other way?

```
int number = 100;
for (int x = number; x <= 2; x--) {

    resultat = resultat + Integer.toString(x);
}
```

Comment: What output do you get ?

Comment: Won't this code never run?  The condition is x <= 2, and x is set to 100.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are right! it's working better now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `+=` in Java is `.=` in PHP:

`result += Integer.toString(x)`. You just need to define `String resultat = ""` above the loop. (And as others noted - fix your loop condition, it's always false)

However, in loops you'd better use a `StringBuilder`. A String is immutable, so every time you use `+` a new string is created (which may be inefficient with bigger loops). Instead:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (...) {
    builder.append(x);
}
String result = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

`x <= 2` is never true for `x = 100`...

You have to change the condition to `x >= 2`

But you can use `+=`

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop just needs a bit of work. You've currently got `x <= 2` when it should be `x >= 2` otherwise the loop will never run as 100 is never smaller than 2!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work in your example because you got the *terminating condition* of the `for` loop wrong. You should write it like this:

```
String resultat = "";
int number = 100;
for (int x = number; x >= 2; x--) {
  resultat = resultat + Integer.toString(x);
}
```

A `for` loop is roughly a `while` loop with some little extras. That's why you have to write the condition like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `StringBuilder.append` like this

```
    int number = 100;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int x = number; x <= 2; x--) {
        builder.append(x);
    }
    String result = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks! Stringbuilder was interesting and news for me.